# Como transformar meu data.frame em uma série de tempo?

Tags: r, data.frame

Meu data frame é esse:

```
IPCA.X04.05.2017 IPCA.Beta.1 IPCA.Beta.2 IPCA.Beta.3 IPCA.Beta.4 IPCA.Lambda.1 IPCA.Lambda.2
2           IPCA      0,0526      0,0442     -0,1269      0,0524        1,3477        0,7203
```

Meu objetivo é criar uma grande base de dados com esses dados (que são diários). Para isso, eu preciso que a primeira coluna tenha as datas, ou seja, que fique assim:

```
            IPCA      Beta.1      Beta.2      Beta.3      Beta.4     Lambda.1         Lambda.2
2     04/05/2017      0,0526      0,0442     -0,1269      0,0524        1,3477        0,7203
```

Como eu posso fazer essa mudança?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode converter desta forma, mas algumas funções de séries temporais exigem que utilize data em formato posxit.

```
df <- data.frame("IPCA", "0.0526", "0.0442")
names(df) <- c("IPCA.X04.05.2017", "IPCA.Beta.1", "IPCA.Beta.2")

df[,1] <- as.character(df[,1])
data <- names(df)[1]
data <- gsub('IPCA.X', '',data)
data <- gsub('\\.', '/', data)

names(df)[1] <- 'IPCA'
df[1,1] <- data

        IPCA IPCA.Beta.1 IPCA.Beta.2
1 04/05/2017      0.0526      0.0442
```